# Access variables in a `useEffect` without triggering the effect when they get updated

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I need to access variables in a `useEffect` but only trigger the method when SOME of them get updated.

For example:

I want to call useEffect when `data` changes, but NOT when `saveTimeout` or `saveMethod` change.

In the same fashion, I want to call `saveMethod` when my component dismounts, but I can't because it needs to be in the dependency array, therefore calling it at every change of `saveMethod`.

```js
function SavingComponent({data, apiInfo}){
    [saveTimeout, setSaveTimeout] = useState(null);

    const saveMethod = useCallBack(()=>{
        clearTimeout(saveTimeout);

        // api call to save the data using apiInfo

    }, [data, saveTimeout, apiInfo])

    // Start a timer to save the data 2 seconds after it is changed (not working)
    useEffect(()=>{
        clearTimeout(saveTimeout);
        setSaveTimeout(setTimeout(saveMethod, 2000));
    }, [data, saveTimeout, saveMethod]);

    // Save immediately on dismount only (not working)
    useEffect(()=>{
      return ()=> { saveMethod(); }
    },[saveMethod])

    return (// some rendering)
}
```

This is an issue I am **constantly running into** with other cases and have to hack around. Usually using a custom `usePrevious` method. I would compare the previous value of the prop to the current and return immediately if the prop I am interested in didn't change.

```js
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}
```

**What is the proper way to only call `useEffect` when SOME dependencies get updated?**

Comment: Maybe this is not really related about question, but the way using `clearTimeout` is similar to function [Debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215941/13107433) ,  may easier to let you control `useEffect`?

Comment: I used debounce before switching to hooks. Is it going to be compatible with a useCallBack Method? But yeah, the question is more about how to handle cases like that in general, the timeout is just an example among dozens.

Comment: I haven't use `debounce` in hook before , but it looks have similar answer using hook under [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58594890/13107433) ?  Although it have four upvote, it may need to try to confirm that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that having variables and functions which are used in `useEffect` as dependencies is recommended and best practice. [This is a very good article written by Dan Abramov](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies) which is deep dive in how `useEffect` works and why you need to follow that best practice.

Now back to your case.

I don't think you want the component re-render when you set `saveTimeout`, so instead use `useState` you can `useRef` for that `saveTimeout = useRef(null)` so you can remove `saveTimeout` from dependencies.

If you don't want `saveMethod` to be in dependencies you can move it inside `useEffect` so that you can remove it from dependencies too.

```js
function SavingComponent({data, apiInfo}){
    const saveTimeout = useRef(null);

    // move saveMethod inside
    useEffect(()=>{
        const saveMethod = ()=>{
            clearTimeout(saveTimeout.current);
            // api call to save the data using apiInfo
        }
        // saveMethod will be called after 2 seconds
        saveTimeout.current = setTimeout(saveMethod, 2000);
    }, [data]);

    // move saveMethod inside
    useEffect(()=>{
        const saveMethod = ()=>{
            // api call to save the data using apiInfo
        }
        // saveMethod will be call when the component unmounted
        // But make sure you are not update any state inside saveMethod
        return saveMethod
    },[])

    return (// some rendering)
}
```

Comment: This article is extremely interesting! It refers to `useReducer` but not `useRef`. Is your general advice to use `useRef` when I need to access a variable that is outside of the scope of my `useEffect` but shouldn't trigger it when changed?

Comment: @RyanPergent In the article it is mentioned that you can move the function inside the `useEffect` so you can remove it from dependency, and there is another way is using `useReducer` as well. `useRef` is another aspect, using it when you want to change the value with change state and re-render the component (the article explains as well)

Comment: Yes, I read the whole thing. Putting the function inside `useEffect` doesn't work when you need to use it in more places, and `useReducer` seems overly complicated. Your suggestion with `useRef` seems both simple and efficient, so that's why I was asking if you recommend it in general (or if it has some sort of caveat).

Comment: In the example that you gave with `saveMethod` called on dismount, you omitted the dependencies. However, my issue is specifically that I have dependencies that stop me from using the `useEffect` for dismount. Do you have an example where dependencies are not omitted?

Comment: The second useEffect did not omit any dependencies, because you create `saveMethod ` inside `useEffect `, the `useEffect ` won't depend on `saveMethod ` method anymore

Comment: Generally, in the complex situation like this, using `useReducer` would be better.

Comment: The saveMethod inside the second useEffect needs to access `data`, so shouldn't that `useEffect` add `data` to its dependency?

Comment: If you need data, The `useReducer ` would definitely be the choice

Comment: Actually after more testing, `useReducer` does not help. I still need to add the state of the reducer to the dependencies, therefore calling the second `useEffect` at every change

Comment: I recommend you read the article a few times to get a better understanding, then apply them correctly in your case. If you till not figure out, please create a new question or update this question with more context. With this context it's the best suggestion I can give