# React Native Picker field refreshed too many times when changing value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state, react-native-picker

I've been struggling with a Picker item which refreshes too many times when changing it's value. The element is used for changing Settings in the app and storing it in the internal storage thanks to `AsyncStorage`.

I'm using `createContext` and my functions in `StorageContext` take care of the retrieving and saving of the setting.

I've made a repro [here](https://snack.expo.io/@javo222/settings_screen_problem).

Changing the options work fine but if you look carefully, it updates too many times. For instance if the user changes from `time1` to `time2`, the picker value will do:
`time1` > `time2` > `time1` > `time2`

On Snack and my mobile it's almost not visible but in the Android simulators it is more... That means my implementation is not the best. This is also confirmed by looking at the console.

How can I improve my code so it works better?
Feel free to change the code directly [here](https://snack.expo.io/@javo222/settings_screen_solution).

The relevant code is in `Settings.js` and `StorageContext.js`

Comment: please provide your code in example, preferably as a  link to edit and play with

Comment: I already provided two links... the original one and one to play with... what else is needed?!

Comment: @remyremy Consider using a debounce or a useCallback then?? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210867/react-native-using-lodash-debounce

Comment: IMHO you're putting too much in the context. I don't see why it is necessary to have the data layer there; you could extract all those DB methods and logic apart, use contexts only to share data among components

Comment: @diedu I'm using the Context API to make some kind of global functions that can be re-used between components. Maybe not the right thing to do?

Comment: What would you recommend keeping in the context? I've tried to move it tona separate component in a new file but I've trouble updating the data woth setDataOnDevice