# How can I check the TextInput change completed in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

Basically, I need to hit search API when the text changed but it's not a good thing to call API on every change in TextInput. So, is there any callback function that exists in this Component that triggers when the user is done with editing (stopped typing)? That would be best if we trigger API when the user stops typing.

I have tried **onEndEditing** but it is not triggered after I stop writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to automatically detect when the user finishes editing you can do something like this

```
 const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
 const timeout = React.useRef(null);

 const onChangeHandler = (value) => {
   clearTimeout(timeout.current);
   setValue(value);
   timeout.current = setTimeout(()=>{
      searchFunction(value)
   }, 2000);
 }

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={ (value) => {onChangeHandler(value)} }
      />
    </View>
```

This will call the search function 2 seconds after the user finishes typing, and the duration will be refreshed whenever they type something

or you can try onBlur instead, those will trigger once the input is not focused anymore and won't trigger just cause you finished typing

Comment: I used 250 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215941/9315094

Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58594890/9315094

**Debounce function should be defined somewhere outside of the render method since it has to refer to the same instance of the function every time you call it as opposed to creating a new instance like it's happening now when you put it in the onChangeText handler function.**

The most common place to define a debounce function is right on the component's object. Here's an example:

CLASS COMPONENT:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     this.onChangeTextDelayed = _.debounce(this.onChangeText, 2000);
   }

   onChangeText(text) {
     console.log("debouncing");
   }

   render() {
     return <Input onChangeText={this.onChangeTextDelayed} />
   }
 }
```

FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT:

```
 function MyComponent(props) {
   const onTextChange = (text) => {
     console.log(text)
   };

   const _onTextChangeHandler = _.debounce(onTextChangeHandler, 1000, []);

    return <Input onChangeText={_onTextChangeHandler} />

 }
```

Comment: I'm using a functional component!

Comment: @AliRehman7141 Sorry for the late response. I've updated the answer. Please check it. If you've already fixed the issue. just skip. Thanks!

Comment: SetTimeout and SetInterval make a memory leak issue if you handled it wrong.